# QuickBlox getting started

Tags: quickblox

I really like to learn how to create a web chat in a WebProject, not to Android, not to IOs, I mean, I want to learn step by step how to create a chat from a PC to other PC, I downloaded the QuickBlox SDK to Web + Facebook, but what is the next step? I followed:

1.-    Register a free QuickBlox account and add your App there.
2.-    Download SDK / code sample for your platform.
3.-    Update credentials in your application code.

from: http://quickblox.com/developers/5_Minute_Guide#1._Create_your_QuickBlox_account
but at the step 3, I do not how to do it. thanks in advance for your appreciated help.

best regards

Comment: Do you read this article ? http://quickblox.com/developers/Web#Getting_started

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy your credentials into Sample. 
Please check this image
http://gyazo.com/adc3c5b7c2ae042fb49950c84e6b0f84

Answer (score 1):

If you want implement the chat in your site, you will need just simply get the short generated html code which you can put on the website anywhere. For this please fill out the corresponding form here:
http://quickblox.com/applications/xmppchat/

Demo - http://quickblox.com/applications/xmppchat/demo.html